# An error occurred while calling o248.save.\n: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision

Tags: python, pyspark, google-bigquery, aws-glue

I am using glue version 4.0 for which i am using spark-biqquery connector jar file as
**`spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.32.2.jar`**

I am writing a df to bigquery but getting below errors:

An error occurred while calling o248.save.

: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

```
1) [Guice/ErrorInCustomProvider]: IllegalArgumentException: 
  at BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:61)
  at BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:106)
      \_ for 3rd parameter
  at BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryClient(BigQueryClientModule.java:106)
  while locating BigQueryClient

Learn more:
  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/ERROR_IN_CUSTOM_PROVIDER

1 error

======================
Full classname legend:
======================
BigQueryClient:           "com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClient"
BigQueryClientModule:     "com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule"
========================
End of classname legend:
========================

    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException(InternalProvisionException.java:251)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1104)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1139)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.v2.Spark3Util.createBigQueryTableInstance(Spark3Util.java:47)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.v2.Spark33BigQueryTableProvider.getBigQueryTableInternal(Spark33BigQueryTableProvider.java:33)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.v2.Spark31BigQueryTableProvider.inferSchema(Spark31BigQueryTableProvider.java:40)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataSourceV2Utils$.getTableFromProvider(DataSourceV2Utils.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.getTable$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:296)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:900)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:360)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:335)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:79)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:73)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:166)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials.fromStream(GoogleCredentials.java:143)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.createCredentialsFromKey(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.<init>(BigQueryCredentialsSupplier.java:78)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule.provideBigQueryCredentialsSupplier(BigQueryClientModule.java:75)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule$$FastClassByGuice$$753248.GUICE$TRAMPOLINE(<generated>)
    at com.google.cloud.bigquery.connector.common.BigQueryClientModule$$FastClassByGuice$$753248.apply(<generated>)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod$FastClassProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:260)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:60)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderMethod.doProvision(ProviderMethod.java:171)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.provision(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:185)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl$CyclicFactory.get(InternalProviderInstanceBindingImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:169)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get(InjectorImpl.java:1101)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected primitive class, but got: class com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:478)
    at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.repackaged.com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:869)
    ... 47 more
]
```

I need to write df using spark-bigquery connector

Comment: how do you write your dataframe (df)? do you have a code snippet example? please add so and question will have more clarity.